# Receiving data from Arduino by using Azure Mobile Services

Tags: rest, azure, arduino

I am working on a project where I need to read and write data from a particular column and a row from Azure Mobile Services to an Arduino. Simply, I need to read and write data to an azure mobile service by an Arduino. The writing part is pretty much done but I am facing a bit of problem in reading the data.

Here is my scenario
1: Upload sensor data from Arduino to Azure mobile service (completed almost)
2: Develop an windows phone app to access the data from azure mobile service (competed)
3: Develop an windows phone app to write data to the azure table(completed)
4: Use the data written in the above step to control my Arduino (STUCK)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an HTTP client to do REST on your Arduino, you could do something like the following:

String read(String table) {
    HttpClient http;

```
http_header_t headers[] = {
    { "X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", "applicationKeyHere" },
    { "Content-Type", "application/json" },
    { NULL, NULL } // NOTE: Always terminate headers with NULL
};

http_request_t request;
http_response_t response;

request.hostname = "mobileservicename.azure-mobile.net";
request.port = 80;
request.path = "/tables/" + table;  //update with your table name

http.get(request, response, headers);

return response.body;
```

}